# Is there an adaptation to the Marching Squares algorithm to make it lossless compression for constrained inputs?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, lossless-compression

I'm using the [Marching Squares algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) to take a lattice of values and turn them into a contour when the values exceed 50%.  My values have the property that most are 0% and 100% where the transitions from 0% to 100% occurs across at most a single intervening value, such that the contour created will pass through every lattice position where the value is greater than 0% and less than 100%.  For example, consider this field of values representing the approximate percentages shown in the greyscale squares of the following image:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   6  71  71  20   0   0
0  28  35 100 100  48  20   0
0 100 100 100 100 100  71   0
0 100 100 100 100 100  71   0
0   9  18 100 100  35   6   0
0   0   9 100 100  28   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

The traditional Marching Squares algorithm would produce a contour as shown in this image:

[image]

The blue field represents the contour and the greyscale squares represent the lattice values for the above data.

Given the resulting contour, I can convert it back to a lattice of numbers again by taking the area covered by the contour for each lattice position as the recreated value for that lattice position.  For the above contour, it looks like this image that shows the same contour and the resulting values converted back to a lattice of values shown by greyscale squares:

[image]

The new values are similar but not exactly the same as the original, some are larger, others are smaller, thus information has been lost and the algorithm is lossy compression.  The decompressed field of values looks approximately like this:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   3  67  70   4   0   0
0  12  43 100 100  59   4   0
0  91 100 100 100 100  70   0
0  88 100 100 100 100  67   0
0   4  27 100 100  43   3   0
0   0   3  88  91  12   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Is there a way to adjust the linear interpolation step to not lose information, or at least come much closer to the original data field?  If not, can the contour have extra points added to resolve this.  For example, perhaps the interpolation step is left as is, but instead of a straight line between the points in the Marching Squares algorithm, there are extra points added along the path to force the desired area in each corner of the four lattice squares considered at each part of the Marching Steps algorithm?

In the lower right area of the example, one step of the Marching Steps algorithm finds these four values:

```
100  28
  0   0
```

The interpolation produces 50% on left side and 70% on top side.  This means on the left, the point A is placed exactly on the border between the 0% square in lower left and the 100% square in upper left.  This means on the top, the point B is placed 70% of the way toward the center of the 28% value in upper right.  The foregoing results in a diagonal line from A to B taking the upper left corner whose value is 100.

We could add additional intervening points between A and B such that the area values are not lost upon return back (decompression) from contour to lattice values.  For example, consider this drawing:

[image]

The original Marching squares gives the points A and B in the drawing.  The yellow highlight shows additional points X, Y, and Z that could be added so that the area covered is 100% in upper left, 0% in lower left, and 28% in upper right.  For the 28%, 14% is handled below point B and 14% above point B.

Is this a known problem that has existing solutions or are there similar problems in compression of images that can be drawn upon to help solve this problem?  Does the proposed solution seem reasonable or can it be simplified further?  I'm concerned that it will be pretty complex to handle the four quadrants for each of the 14 variations of Marching Squares that produce lines, so if there is a way to simplify this, I'd like to find it.

In summary, would like to adjust the computation of the blue contour, such that the area of each lattice square covered by the contour matches the original data used to create the blue contour, and thus have lossless compression to convert the lattice into a contour that is perfectly reversible.